# Change kill-line to delete-line function

Tags: emacs

Standard `C-k` is kill-line function-> delete line and put it into kill-ring, I want use only something like 'delete-line'. Have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `delete-line` function like this:

```lisp
(defun delete-line ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-region (point) (line-end-position)))
```

The function above mimics the behaviour of the function `kill-line` called without argument on a line with remaining non-blanks characters after point. You'll have to elaborate a bit if you want the exact behaviour of `kill-line`.

Comment: Rustem: You should accept the answer, then. See the FAQ on asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want.  Place this line into your .emacs.

```
(global-set-key "\C-k" 'delete-line)
```

You can also try it out in your current session with M-: and then type it in and see if that's what you really want.

Comment: I'm running 24.0.94.2 and I don't have `delete-line`.

Comment: Sure, but there are no same function. **Symbol's function definition is void: delete-line**